# Allowing temporary access to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I have a client app that connects to an Elastic Beanstalk server app. Some of my users need to register. But when the registration form loads it needs to get some data from DynamoDB so the user can choose between a few options.

The problem is that I set up my server in a way that any request to the server that is not authenticated (no auth tokens previously obtained by the client app from Cognito) gets denied. Of course, if a person is going to register they are not authenticated, which means they do not have access to the information from DynamoDB they need to register. It is only a couple of pieces of information I need, so it is very frustrating.

What I have thought about how to solve this:

1. Putting a long string of characters in the client app that gets sent to the server when a request is made for ONLY the couple of pieces of information I need. The server would also have that same string stored somewhere and would then compare them. If they match, then it returns the info requested. As I said, this would be done only for the 2 pieces of info I need, everything else would still be secure.
2. Leave the two routes public in my API that lead to the pieces of info I need (I know, it is a bad idea).

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Why is 2 a bad idea?

Comment: I think it may lead to abuse or DDoS attacks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using cognito there is also a concept of an anonymous guest user which can have its own role assigned.

You can treat the [anonymous guest user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/switching-identities.html) like a regular cognito user (it can have a role assigned), however you would scope its permissions down to the minimum it requires to perform these operations.

Alternatively use option 2, the API could call a Lambda that would return the necessary information simply reading the data. You would possibly want to look at caching the results as well to avoid your API Gateway endpoint being abused.

Comment: If I leave it open, wouldn't it be better then to go with option #1? Thanks!

Comment: Personally option 2 is simpler, if you enable the API Gateway endpoint with caching you do not need to worry too much about performance. As it does not contain anything sensitive it will be fine